# Axios Vuejs POST request with parameter

Tags: post, vue.js, axios

I need to send file via axios POST request to a remote API with the following parameter : 'operation' => 'x' and 'files' => the file itself.

The file is a pdf file.
I tried this:

```
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('operation', 'x');

formData.append('files', this.file);

axios({

  url: 'http://xxxxx',

  method: 'POST',

  data: formData,

  headers: {

    Accept: 'application/json',

    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'

     }

    }).then(response => {

      console.log(response);

    })

    .catch(error => {

      console.log(error);

    });

}
```

But I cannot get it work. I trieed also using set method on formData but it doesn't work aswell. Is there something I am making wrong?
PS. I tried with POSTMan and it works so it is not an API problem.
Thank you.

Comment: I believe headers should be in a config object. So: config: { headers: { .... } }

Comment: Can you clarify how it does not "work"? What's the error/behavior you're seeing?

Comment: isn't the method for axios.post? I think there is something wrong with your syntax.

Comment: what, exactly, is `this.file`? The file needs to be a file form element previously selected by the user, look at this example https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/examples/upload/index.html#L27

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this help

```js
axios.post(url, {params: {}}).then().catch()
```